# Compile for 32-bit Architectures using MinGW-w64

Tags: mingw-w64

I have installed MinGW-w64 for compiling to 64-bit. But it appears that I have to install two seperate versions of MinGW-w64 to get support for 32-bit.

I tried that, using batch files and powershell scripts and what not, and it wasn't very good in the end.

There appears to be multilib version which can handle both using the `-m32` flag for 32-bit although I am not sure if that is the how I should compile for both 64-bit and 32-bit.

So what is the proper way get MinGW-w64 to be able to compile for both 64 and 32 bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version you are using is not `multilib` enabled so you won't be able to compile `32-bit` programs using the MinGW-w64.

You need [this version](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/ray_linn/gcc-9.x-with-ada/x86_64-w64-mingw32-9.1.0-crt-6.0.0-lib32_lib64.7z/download) for using it on a `64-bit` platform but in order to be able to compile both `32-bit` and `64-bit`.

Comment: But that is horrendously outdated.
And there's this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/ray_linn/gcc-9.x-with-ada/x86_64-w64-mingw32-9.1.0-crt-6.0.0-lib32_lib64.7z/download
Which isn't outdated, rather more up-to-date. But is it the right one?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the link with the latest one. That has a multilib toolchains (targetting both Win32 and Win64)