# Building 32Bit and 64Bit application uitilizing mingw-w64 and cmake

Tags: cmake, 32bit-64bit, mingw-w64

I need to build a shared library on windows (dll) in 32bit and 64bit.
The build is controlled with cmake, the compiler is mingw64

```
This is my cmake file:

#64Bit Build (works fine)
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib SHARED mylib.c)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mylib PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
target_link_options(mylib PUBLIC -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -s -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output.map )

#32Bit Build (linking issues)
ADD_LIBRARY(mylib32 SHARED mylib.c)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(mylib32 PROPERTIES PREFIX "" COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32" LINK_FLAGS "-m32")
target_link_options(mylib32 PUBLIC --verbose -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -s -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output.map)
```

I get a lot of complaints during linking due to 32Bit incomatibility of many linked libraries.
I can reduce the amount of complaints, when I am specifically add 32Bit libraries to the search path like this:

`target_link_options(mylib32 PUBLIC --verbose -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -s -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output.map -L/msys64/mingw32/lib -L/msys64/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/msys64/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.3.0)`

But there are still some incompatibilities left: like the dllcrt.a which is always linked from the 64Bit mingw path,
which seems kind of hard coded into gcc/ld.

I even tried to use an empty spec fiel, which gave nor results:
`target_link_options(mylib32 PUBLIC -specs=myspe --verbose -Wl,--exclude-all-symbols -s -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-Map=output.map -L/msys64/mingw32/lib -L/msys64/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/msys64/mingw32/lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/10.3.0)`

Typical error message I get:

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/dllcrt2.o' is incompatible with i386 output

Comment: Do you use the same compiler for both 32bit and 64bit executables?

Comment: yes, same compiler,

Comment: Why do you not use the 32bit compiler for the 32bit executables?

Comment: As far as I know it s very complicated to maintain 2 Build environments with cmake for the same project. 
The usage of the "-m32" to generate i386 output seems to be a common usecase, so initially it looked like the much simpler way.

Comment: If the compiler had `multilib` enabled, then `-m32` would work, because the 32bit libraries would be included as well. Not sure if anyone still builds multilib compilers for mingw.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, I have not been aware of the "multilib" keyword.
I installed Mingw via msys2, but apperently there are other distributions which have multilib enabled, at least according to this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685298/compile-for-32-bit-architectures-using-mingw-w64

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out a solution for my case:

the crt* stuff is startup code, which is not needed in the case of libraries.
So I added the `-nostartfiles` flag, and my library links fine.
I guess in case off an application one can probably link the 32bit startfiles manualy as a workaround.

`SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(amprio_seednkey32 PROPERTIES PREFIX "" COMPILE_FLAGS "-m32 -nostartfiles" LINK_FLAGS "-m32 -nostartfiles")`

Anyhow, this all feels like a dirty Workaround, I still wonder what is the best way to link 32Bit and 64Bit using mingw-w64.